# How to list all webcams in Chrome via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromium

When trying to enumerate all media devices via JS in Chrome, only the first webcam is shown. `chrome://settings/content/camera` shows both cameras, and I use the following code (which works fine in Firefox):

```js
if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
    console.log('getUserMedia supported.');
    console.log(navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video:true, audio:true}));
    navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
    .then(function(devices) {
      devices.forEach(function(device) {
        console.log(device.kind + ": " + device.label +
                    " id = " + device.deviceId);
      });
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message);
    });
}
```

which results in Chrome the following output:

```
getUserMedia supported.
Promise (…)
audioinput:  id = 
videoinput:  id = 
audiooutput:  id =
```

and in Fireofox in

```
getUserMedia supported.
Promise (…)
videoinput:  id = DACXIZdjYm/DS9P8hbf/BCRzmBzblci5EuCvWYc67p4=
videoinput:  id = 9cc0CmMqsHyJQuZle9oi0LiA9AjohJ4UATNx8i0wmBY=
audioinput:  id = DQhXmow8zdrRtM1GgHpW0qNh6oQfqRy9LXqNWze1Gfw=
audioinput:  id = AwWokTstiDOqKcvVUScbL1Y+RSYVkGBlzht8fEeA3ko=
audioinput:  id = CGowMcq2i9pCOOoscC636DmeQI2CODmX5M0RNlDJLKc=
audioinput:  id = n33kMAKs2Nmb+ydgoXaElXDUMKf9Je7KVQ74w6+/oqc=
```

I of course allowed access to webcam, when Chrome asked.
Also I enabled 'Experimental Web Platform features' flag (which should not be necessary anymore by now, but who knows…)

Where is the problem? Is it on my side, or on Chrome`s?

I also would be happy to get feedback if its only on my machine, for some reason, or if you can reproduce the issue – you can use this fiddle to try at your machine: https://jsfiddle.net/emudz25w/ (open console on lower right to see output.)

Chromium
Version 90.0.4430.212 (Developer Build) built on Debian 11.0, running on Debian 11.0 (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it occured because i forgot to give permissions on Webcam and AudioDevices.
Try to reload the page and give the permissions in the popup. If no popup occurs, you can set permissions on the lock-icon left to the address-bar (in Chrome).

After that it worked without a problem.

[Worked after reload, runs once before permission was given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y22gG.gif)

Comment: "I of course allowed access to webcam, when Chrome asked"

Comment: Refresh after granting permissions didn't work?

Comment: Nope. Does the jsfiddle I linked above work for you?

Comment: Yes, on the second run. You can watch it in the link i added to my answer. Used Chrome Version 97.0.4692.99 on Windows.

Are you running your code in an iframe or some sort of a Virtual-Machine?

Comment: Thanks for your time & feedback, maybe it has just been the version – for plain Chromium it now runs also for me (only in Vivaldi not yet, in which I tried it again only before, today)